# What is the correct way to achieve intersection of multiple clip paths?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

As described in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003171/how-to-identify-which-clip-paths-apply-to-a-path-or-fill-in-pdf-vector-graphics/17021865), I am trying to recreate an SVG from vector graphics commands in a PDF and I am facing some difficulty in the part where I need to intersect a set of clip paths. For instance, the [raw SVG](http://pastebin.com/WSyG30ft) has a few clip path elements line #16 which need to be intersected and applied on the rectangle fill (line #17) to obtain what looks like this: [image: expected outcome of applying intersected clip paths on rectangle fill].

I am not clear about the correct and the best way to achieve intersection of multiple clip paths in an SVG. I wasn't able to find much information about this on the web except [this one](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_clip.html), going by which I came up with [this SVG](http://pastebin.com/5NGRxntK) where I introduce a sequence of additional *clipPath* elements which try to intersect the current intersection with the next original *clipPath* to be added to the intersection set. This approach seems rather inelegant to me. Besides, that SVG doesn't seem to work on some versions of Firefox (ESR 17.x) though it renders the expected result on Firefox 5, Chrome and IE. Is there something wrong with the SVG? Or even if it is correct, is there a simpler/better way to achieve the intersection?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in Firefox, raise a bug in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: @RobertLongson Sure, will file a bug. But assuming that my SVG is in fact correct, is there a better way to achieve intersection of clip paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've done it seens reasonable. There's a [w3c example](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/masking-path-07-b.html) in the testsuite.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead with that approach and ended up with the SVG http://pastebin.com/d9ni4dYQ corresponding to a page in a PDF. Unfortunately, though the shapes in the SVG are correct, the fill colors seen in the PDF are not seen when the SVG is rendered by any of the standard browsers. The upper left triangle in the SVG is supposed to have a yellow fill and the lower right triangle is expected to have a light blue-green fill. I do see 2 rectangular clip paths (ids clip_2 and clip_3) in the SVG **XML** having these colors, but why isn't SVG rendering displaying these colors?

Comment: I posted this follow-up question as a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288182/fill-colors-associated-with-svg-clip-paths-what-is-the-expected-behaviour. Could you please reply there in case you identified the problem with the mentioned SVG?