# Fill colors associated with SVG clip paths - what is the expected behaviour?

Tags: pdf, svg, vector-graphics

This is related to my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042288/what-is-the-correct-way-to-achieve-intersection-of-multiple-clip-paths) where I try to extract vector graphics in a PDF to an SVG file. I obtained [this SVG](http://pastebin.com/d9ni4dYQ) corresponding to a page in a PDF. Unfortunately, though the shapes in the SVG are correct, the fill colors seen in the PDF are not seen when the SVG is rendered by any of the standard browsers. The upper left triangle in the SVG is supposed to have a yellow fill and the lower right triangle is expected to have a light blue-green fill. I do see 2 rectangular clip paths (ids clip_2 and clip_3) in the SVG XML having these colors, but why isn't SVG rendering displaying these colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath):

> The raw geometry of each child element exclusive of rendering
>   properties such as ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stroke-width’ within a
>   ‘clipPath’ conceptually defines a 1-bit mask (with the possible
>   exception of anti-aliasing along the edge of the geometry) which
>   represents the silhouette of the graphics associated with that
>   element. Anything outside the outline of the object is masked out.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I understood that specification entirely. Does it imply the fill colors associated with a clip path will not have any effect on the region (i.e. rendered portion) on which that clip path is applied? In the [SVG mentioned earlier](http://pastebin.com/d9ni4dYQ), what then is the purpose of the fill color attribute in the child elements of `<clipPath>`? I created the SVG from a PDF which displays the clipped regions as having fill colors that match the colors in the 2 `clipPath`s in the SVG.

Comment: Yes, the fill color has no effect on elements inside a `<clipPath>`. The fill should be put on the elements that are rendered, e.g `<path d="..." fill="green" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>`.

Comment: Thanks again. So does that mean that the PDF's representation of the fill color associated with the clipped region is not in full conformance with SVG specifications? I'm asking this because the PDF clearly had fill colors associated with two _eoclip_ commands and not with the renderable _paint_/_stroke_ commands. And yet the PDF viewer displayed the colors in those clipped regions, unlike the SVG renderers.

Comment: Why would the PDF spec have to conform to the SVG spec? These are two separate languages with different syntax and so on. The PDF->SVG converter should try to find another way of representing the PDF state in SVG.